# How state data send to another screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

my code like this. I get data on first screen and I stored that data in state but I not able to received that data in another screen.

1)

```
getCharity = (item) => {
        this.setState({updateCharityName: item.charityName})
    }
```

2)

```
<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('AppsettingScreen',{UserName:this.state.updateCharityName}),this.getCharity(item)}} 
style={{ backgroundColor: '#ff8787', width: 51, height: 20, borderRadius: 20 }} >
<Text style={{ color: 'white', marginHorizontal: 8, width: 55 }}>Select</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

second screen:-

```
1)const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('UserName');
2)<Text style={styles.txtheadvw}>{(JSON.stringify(data))}</Text>
```

Comment: try to pass navigate as a callback after your state update.

Answer (score 4):

Here have some example.
[Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

1.Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate 
function: navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })

2.Read the params in your screen component: route.params.